# Drawing a circle and line onto a JFrame using JPanels without GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Currently I am trying to draw a line and a circle (which will become animated, like a wheel) onto my canvas.

I have a constructor called `WheelAnimation()`.

Within this constructor, I have these two implementation classes, the first one is the circle:

```
class CircleComponent extends JComponent
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            // repaint();
            g2.fillOval(i, 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}

final CircleComponent component2 = new CircleComponent();
panel.add(component2);
```

And this draws the line under the circle:

```
class LineComponent extends JComponent
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.drawLine(120, 120, 380, 120);
    }
}

final LineComponent component = new LineComponent();
panel.add(component);
```

If I use a `setLayout` method such as: `panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));`

I can make the two items show up (though their formatting is not good).

http://puu.sh/8fm9B/4f1dc1d0e5.png

But if I remove the `setLayout` method, nothing shows up onto my frame, despite the coordinates staying the same.

Could someone tell me why this is happening and give me a recommendation on how to set those layouts and make them show up?

Answer (score 0):

> I can make the two items show up (though their formatting is not good).

When you use a layout manager it is responsible for setting the size and location of the component added to the panel.

If you don't use a layout manager then your application code is responsible for setting the size and location of each component.

Comment: That part I understand (Layout Manager determines where each component is placed within the frame). However, if I remove the layout manager, nothing shows up at all.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, did you read my answer??? Did you set the size and location of each component???

Comment: Apologies! I have so far used `.setBounds()` with both `component` and `component`, but nothing is showing up. I think I'm doing it wrong..

Comment: @theGreenCabbage, yes setBounds() is ok as well. Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.